# append to list - instance attribute

Tags: python

I want to add a list as a Python class instance attribute (i.e. not a class attribute), and then add a class method which will append items to the list.

e.g. we have an Employee class and each employee may have won different awards which will be stored in a list.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        employeeAwards = []

    def addAward(self, Award):
        employeeAwards.append(Award)
```

However if do this, I get an "unresolved reference" error on the instance attribute (employeeAwards).

Where should I declare the class instance attribute?

Comment: You want a *class method* that appends to an *instance attribute*?! Or do you mean an *instance method*?

Comment: `self.employeeAwards = []` and then `self.employeeAwards.append(Award)`

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind it to `self`:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        self.employeeAwards = []

    def addAward(self, Award):
        self.employeeAwards.append(Award)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [septi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/531222/septi) pointed out the correct solution already: bind it to `self`.

[Here](http://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide)'s an interesting discussion about **class** vs **instance** variables: Every variable (or method) you bind to `self` is in fact an *instance variable*.

Class variables would look like this:

```
class Employee(object):
    employeeAwards = []

    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        ...
```

Comment: This is also a valid answer, but you should be careful when using a list as a class attribute. Pay attention that when using append to the list, you are actually updating the class attribute and not the instance attribute.